# Remove DUO auth completely from ubuntu server 18.04 - two factor auth

Tags: 18.04, server, login, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server with DUO authentication. This DUO interferes with my [capistrano](https://capistranorb.com/) deployment (rails app)

For such, I have removed duo auth with `sudo apt-get remove duo-unix`

Then I logged out of the server, and when trying to access again:

```
bash: /usr/sbin/login_duo: No such file or directory
Connection to 10.5.121.xxx closed.
```

I don't really intend to recover the server. I can delete it and create a new one. I would like to know how to remove this duo factor auth completely. Removing duo-unix wasn't enough because some line in some code requests `login_duo`. I want to completely delete duo requests

Comment: Check for "DUO authentication" changes in `/etc/passwd`, check if `/bin/login` is bad with `sudo debsums login`. Consider `sudo apt-get install --reinstall login`.

Comment: While `duo-unix` is installed, `dpkg -L duo-unix` will show the files in the package.